# Why some apps refuse to be closed?

Tags: 8.1, apps

Since the introduction of Windows Phone 8.1 I noticed a strange behavior.

After hit the Back button for the last time in **some** apps (closing it) I still can see them in the app switcher (hold back button).

Some examples: *Facebook, Calendar (built in), Tweetium*.

If I'm in start screen and hit Back I don't go there but if I switch using the app switcher I can go straight to the place a left the app.

If a close it by swiping down or hitting "x" it kills the app.

I'm waiting for a better explanation than "they are working in background" or "it's like Windows 8.1", please.

Comment: What's wrong with the "they are working in the background" explanation?

Comment: @Indrek Maybe I didn't explained correctly. Actually I'm frustrated because in my phone if I position it in a post in Facebook (for example) and hit back to close, after 10 minutes if I switch back to this app it will "resuming" forever (>3sec) and will load like I had clicked in the tile with the app entirely closed. So it's not in background, it's almost freezing.

Comment: @Indrek Wonder if it work like that for everybody.

Comment: I see that behaviour too, on 8.1. I thought this was related to whether or not the app was allowed to run in the background in Battery Saver, but one of the apps that lingers in the app list on my phone is Facebook Messenger, which (now that I check it) doesn't even have the "Allow app to run in the background" option. Curious...

Comment: @Indrek I think it's related to the app be made using new 8.1 SDK instead of 8.0 SDK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this behavior is due to the different runtimes available for apps to use in Windows Phone 8.1.

Since Windows Phone 8.1, there was a major change to the lifecycle of apps. Tapping back from the main page of an 8.1 WinRT (Universal) will not close an app. This is also the same lifecycle you see in Windows 8.1 apps.

However, if the app uses WP 8.0 (Silverlight), the app will close by tapping back from the first page of an app (unless the dev screwed up and has a circular navigation happening, in which it will go to another page in the app instead of leaving the app).

There is a variety of choices for devs today; 8.0 Silverlight, 8.1 Silverlight and WinRT (Windows 8.1 model).

Just to be clear, apps **never run in the background** on Windows Phone. They go into a **suspended** state. If the app has been suspended for a long time, been pushed down too far by other apps or if you close it manually they go into **terminated** state.

When you go back to a suspended app, you'll see the "resuming..." notice. This is when the developer loads the data that was saved when it was suspended. So from your perspective, it was never closed.

-A small summary of what does run in the background-
What does run the background are "background tasks" which are small snippets of code that run independently of your app, even when the app has been terminated. That's why you have the option in settings to disable background tasks.

Comment: So the apps that you see in the switcher but cannot switch to from the home screen using the Back button - which runtime are they using?

Comment: There is something unusual going on if the app cannot be backed into from Start if it was the last opened. I can have Microsoft investigate this and report back here. Do you have an example of which app does this?

Comment: Thanks Ambassador. I knew this kind of question could be answer only by someone with great internal knowledge.

Comment: @LanceMcCarthy Facebook Messenger, for example. Or the built-in Calendar app.

Comment: @Indrek I can successfully open any of those apps by tapping the tile even though they are suspended in app switcher. Sometimes they crash.

Comment: @VitorCanova It's not opening them from the tile that's the issue here.

Comment: Okay, just so we're all on the same page, here's what happens on my Lumia 920 with WP 8.10.14219.341. Step 1: open Calendar. Step 2: press Back to exit Calendar. Step 3: on the Start screen, press Back; nothing happens. Step 4: still on the Start screen, long-press Back to see the app switcher, observe Calendar still in the list. Question: if I closed Calendar, why does it still show up in the app switcher? If it's suspended in the background, why can't I switch to it with the Back button?

Comment: @Indrek the behavior try to match W8.1 behavior where apps closed stay in memory for fast open next time. Missing the "fast" part in my case because the "resuming" forever.

Comment: Here is what I think is happening with the Calendar app. Clicking back from the app's entry page removes it from the back stack (that's why you can't back into it from the main page), but it is still persisted. So you'll see it in the task switcher, and when you switch to it you'll end up at the same place you left it in (i.e. slide to a different month, resuming it will bring you back to that state).

Comment: @VitorCanova IF the app crashes, it's because it didn't properly handle resuming. The dev has to manage what state it is resuming from (suspended is different than tombstoned). It sounds like they're not resuming from tombstoned properly.